# what is the difference between naming a subquery vs using AS to alias the subquery result?

Tags: sql, alias

Is there any difference between these two syntaxes?

```
select * from (some query) result
select * from (some query) AS result
```

Comment: The `AS` keyword is optional and makes no difference.

Comment: @jarlh: except when using Oracle where it's not allowed at all

Comment: thank you. I assumed this was the case. But not knowing for certain was bothering me

Comment: @JamesJoshuaStreet if you check the documentation (for [mysql, in example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html)), optionals keywords are written [like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two (they do the same thing).

However some databases have a preference one way or the other.  For instance, Oracle does not support `as` for table aliases.  On the other hand, MS Access requires them.

Personally, I only use `as` for column aliases.  I use them for column aliases because it is very easy to leave out a column, so:

```
select x y
```

works even when you mean:

```
select x, y
```

The `as` is a statement of intent for *column* aliases.

There is no danger of such confusing in the `from` clause, so I find that `as` for table aliases is unnecessary.

Comment: *"There is no danger of such confusing in the from clause"* as long as one doesn't use the deprecated way to write joins (which is still used, as we can see in many SQL questions there), `select ... from table1, table2` / `select ... from table1 as table2`

Comment: @Cid . . . That would never be an issue in code that I write or that anyone I work with writes.  In addition, such an mistake would almost always generate an error in the query, which is fine.  The problem with column aliases is that the query runs, and you *think* it is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between both statements above. "AS" is just a more explicit way of mentioning the alias.